# How to set headers in api call om nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am working on authentication in nodeJs. I have created successfully login API and it works well on the postman. I'm stuck on client side. It does not set token on headers. I am using the passport, jwt for authentication.

My code is:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  var name = {
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  // let m = '';
  // console.log(name)
  request({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/login",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
    body: name
  }, function (error, response) {
    if (response.body.error == true) {
      req.flash('errorMsg', response.body.message);
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {

      // localStorage.setItem('token', response.body.token);
      // console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
      // req.headers['authorization'] = response.body.token;
      // res.setHeader('authorization', response.body.token);
      // req.session['token'] = response.body.token;
      // console.log(req.session['token'])
      // res.set({
      //    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      //    'authorization':response.body.token
      //   });
      //   res.setHeader('authorization', response.body.token);
      //   req.headers['authorization'] = response.body.token;


      res.redirect('/secret');
      next();
    }
  });
  // console.log(m);
});
```

and my middleware is:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  var token = req.body.token || req.session['token'] || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || localStorage.getItem('token');
  req.headers['authorization'] = token;
  console.log(req.session['token'], token)
  console.log(req.headers['authorization'], config.jwtSecret);
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {

        res.json({
          'message': 'Failed to authenticate user'
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    // logger.warn('Unauthorized');
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  console.log(req.headers['authorization'])
});
```

I have tried all possible to set the token in headers but it didn't work well. If I get my token on app.use middleware then I can verify token easily but it didn't allow to set my token.

How can I do this??

Comment: I haven't tried this code. But I have an idea of using the whole information for looking at the required information You can just log the value of '**req**' instead of '**req.headers['something']**' ....

Answer (score 0):

**Best way!**

```js
router.get('/your-route', async (req, res) => {
    //...
    res.setHeader('your-key', 'your-value');
    //..
})
```

You can see output in header tab in browser or postman
`your-key: your-value`